# CakePHP error: cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' on Centos

Tags: php, linux, caching, centos

I tried almost everything to fix this issue, but still doesnt work :(. Error is below.

```
`Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_cs' to File cache in /var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 325

Warning: /var/www/html/orangescrum/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 384

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:181 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1 /var/www/html/orangescrum/app/Config/core.php(292): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2 /var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/var/www/html/o...') #3 /var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(175): Configure::bootstrap(true) #4 /var/www/html/orangescrum/app/webroot/index.php(77): include('/var/www/html/o...') #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/orangescrum/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 181`.
```

The most common advice (permission issue with the folder -/var/www/html/orangescrum/... should be fixed by using this:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/orangescrum
```

Just to make sure, there is a permission check:

```
[root@hubud0635 orangescrum]# stat -c %a app
777
[root@hubud0635 orangescrum]# cd app
[root@hubud0635 app]# ls -a
.   Config   Controller  index.php  Locale  Plugin  tmp     View
..  Console  .htaccess   Lib        Model   Test    Vendor  webroot
[root@hubud0635 app]# stat -c %a tmp
777
```

Subfolders in Cache are existing:

```
[root@hubud0635 tmp]# cd cache
[root@hubud0635 cache]# ls -a
.  ..  models  persistent  views
```

Ive created a host file for application Orangescrum.The content of this file is below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/orangescrum
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
<Directory /var/www/html/orangescrum>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If any other further question, lets ask me. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS have SElinux enabled by default.

```
sestatus
```

will show if its really active.

How to deactivate it:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
update line to: SELINUX=disabled
reboot
```